# Set decimal number on Y axis

Tags: javafx-2

I have a data series with 5 decimals such as 0,58861; now I plot with a XYChart as LineChart but I only see 3 numbers plotted, i.e. 0,58 or .584.

I have also tryed to change font size 
`yAxis.setTickLabelFont(Font.font("Arial", 5));`

with no result, I always have 3 numbers plotted.

Below are two picture to show this behavior.

How to set more decimal on Y axis?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So what is wrong with that y-axis plotted numbers? You can think 0.58 as 0.58000 etc. These are just major ticks and not the points (numbers) of your data series. If you want to see more ticks and hence more precise measure values change the tickUnit parameter:

```
NumberAxis(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double tickUnit)
```

But this time if your datas range (`upperBound`-`lowerBound`) is large according to `tickUnit` then your graph's shape and form will degrade. To overcome this problem play with `lowerBound` and `upperBound` values to show only part of your data series as like they have been zoomified.
To change the tick label font and size, try:

```
yAxis.setTickLabelFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.MEDIUM, 18));
```

Comment: Hi Uluk thanks for your reply: my problem is in decimal number displayed.
My series data has 4 or 5 decimals,and I only get 3 decimals plotted, i.e. my serie = 0,58431 I get displayed .584
It is not a problem of grid tick appearance, since I just have grid setted as
double max = max + ( max * 0.001 );
double min = min - ( min * 0.001 );

final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(start-1, end+1, 10);
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(min, max, max/500);

Comment: Where are you displaying your data series? They are not visible on the screenshots that you have posted in your question. Also your question was `How to set more decimal on Y axis?`, which in my understanding it is about grid ticks.

Comment: Updated my question with two pictures: first one shows data as I have in mySQL with 4 decimals data.
Second one shows how it is plotted,(Y scale on the left graph part);I always have 3 decimals even with grid setted as 0.0001
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(min, max, 0.0001);
PS actual plot display close column values

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font size will not help. You have to change the tick label formatter using the [`setTickLabelFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#setTickLabelFormatter(javafx.util.StringConverter)) function.

Comment: I have read in Oracle FX examples about setTickLabelFormatter but it seems this method is useful only to add prefix and suffix, as stated in Oracle doc

yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis,"$ ",null));

The NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter class adds prefixes and suffixes to the tick labels of the specified axis. In Example 5-2, the formatter defines a dollar sign ($) prefix for each tick label of the vertical axis. The null value for the suffix parameter indicates that no suffixes are added.

I don't need to add any, just plot 4 or 5 decimals I have in my data serie

Comment: Ok problem solved: solution was

yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter(yAxis){
            @Override
        public String toString(Number object){
            return String.format("%6.4f", object);
        }
    });